# VNC Serve Part of Desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc

Is it possible to only serve a specified box of your desktop via VNC, instead of the entire thing?

Comment: Which make and model of VNC server?

Comment: TightVNC v1.3.9

Answer (score 0):

Remote management/access can be limited to a specific application (window) via the setting options under the "Display" tab of the TightVNC server.